# mingw C program with setup in its name won't run (windows 7)

Tags: c, windows, mingw, command-line-interface

I've written the classic 3 line "Hello World" in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\r\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Compile on linux targeting win32:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o helloWorld.exe -g -march=i586 helloWorld.c
```

Move the hellowWorld.exe to windows 7 machine, runs fine ... Now, I rename it to anything with 'setup' in the name, like **hellosetupWorld.exe** and UAC fires when I try to run it, and it fails to run even if I answer the UAC popup 'yes it's ok, run it'. Later I get a popup asking if my program installed properly.

This seems to be new behavior. Has anyone else seen this?  I've tested this on a virgin windows 7 from MSDN in a virtual machine with almost nothing else installed. Same problem.

Heh ... not just mingw. This happens if I compile with visual studio at the command line,
like 
    cl Hello.c

I get exactly the same behavior. Put 'setup' somewhere in the name, and the program won't run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a natively built EXE on my Win7 box. It runs as expected whether named `test.exe` or `setupTest.exe` or `helloSetupWorld.exe`. I wonder if it might be something to do with the cross-compilation.

Comment: I just did it by compiling that exact code (minus <strings.h>) with cl at the windows command line. Rename it, and it fails.

Comment: It doesn't happen if you use visual studio to make a windows cli template (it then uses stdafx.h, and the main signature is a little different).

Comment: It gets better. mingw is a red herring. If I build the code at the commandline (windows 7, visual studio 2010) with cl, The program cannot have 'setup' anywhere in its name (if you want it to actually run). However, if I build it in the visual studio GUI ... exact same code as posted above (minus strings.h) ... it runs independenly of how I name it.

Comment: I was building with MinGW. Doesn't seem to matter whether I do it via Code::Blocks or the command-line, it runs properly regardless of filename. I'll try VS on the command-line momentarily.

Comment: I'm running Win7 SP1 and I think Windows Defender on my virgin VM, but I get very similar behavior on my corporate machine with Microsoft forefront endpoint protection (enterprise version of same thing AFAIK)  It's gotta be the Defender that's doing it.

Comment: Nope. Just turned off Windows Defender and still have the problem.

Comment: mind sharing the command-line settings you used for VS? Can't get link to cooperate with me.

Comment: I ran a Visual Studio Command prompt (Start/Visual Studio 2010/Visual Studio Tools/Visual Studio Command prompt) Then I just typed:  "cl Hello.c" and I got an .exe

Comment: Reproduced! Oddly enough, if I keep the exe as, say, "main.exe" it looks and runs like a normal executable. But if I rename it to "helloSetupWorld.exe", the UAC shield appears on the exe file and I get the UAC prompt upon running it. Renaming back to "main.exe" removes the UAC shield and prompt.

Comment: Not surprisingly, the word 'install' in the name causes the same problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not going crazy ;-)   This is really disturbing behavior.

Comment: Yep, "helloInstall.exe" pops the UAC shield/prompt too. I wonder why MinGW builds aren't triggering this for me, though? It was just that one VS build. And yes, it's very odd behavior, and somewhat disturbing since I would hope Windows would use more than just a filename to determine whether a file is an installer or not.

Comment: For me ... the program doesn't even run as far as I can tell. I allow UAC to continue, and I get a momentary flash of a ?command prompt? window. Too quick to really tell.

Comment: I think it's the combo of the name and some artifact in the PE executable ... If I build with VS GUI it works fine.  I lost a day to this.

Comment: The program runs for me; the process shows up for just a second in Task Manager's Process view. I think the command-line window (which I get too, by the way) is because the file built as a console exe.